# Select Item in Asp.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

good morning.

i am trying to do a list of selecting items in asp.net.

the purpose of it , is a page of "Contact Us" .

so i did a textboxes, a buttom.

but, i need thay to select item from a list, any one have any idea?

thanks all !

Comment: Show your code to show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select one item from a list then you could use a

[DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0dzka5sf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or ListBox as [Akram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/657974/akram-shahda) suggested

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options including [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) and [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx).

Comment: i am trying to use the dropdownlist, any one have a code exple, please ?:)

thanks!